# AWS EC2 : No HTTP Traffic after reboot but SSH is ok

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, http, amazon-ami

I have a small ami EC2 instance @ AWS.

I had to reboot yesterday and after reboot, I couldn't access the websites hosted on the EC2 while there was no problem at all through SSH.

Things I checked and found to be Okay:

- Network rules, seems ok:

  Allow all from 0.0.0.0/0 (Inbound and Outbond)
- IPTables - seems ok - Only allow.

I tried associating another Elastic IP but to no avail.
I can't `telnet` to the public IP address either.

I believe it's some misconfiguration issue done by me.

I would be grateful if someone could point me to some troubleshooting steps.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: There could be many reasons for this issue, can you tell what were the last configurations you touched?

Comment: Also, please try running `telnet` to your machine in port 22 and tell me the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be a long shot, but are the httpd/apache/nginx or whatever web server you are using actually started?

Comment: Thank you Frederik !
It was only that !
It's the first time I've seen httpd & mysql that don't start at a reboot !

Comment: a reboot should be added to you testing suite and re-run all tests after that.  if you make an AMI, then terminate and launch again should also be added.

Answer (score 0):

I know little about Amazon's services, but my answer should be general to UNIX-like system.

Your problem may occure due to interrupted OS startup procedure, due to ie. error in `/etc/fstab` or other filesystem problems. `sshd` most often starts early in the boot process, before most other services, this could explain why it's available. I've seen this issue under Ubuntu multiple times, especially that I used to customize service startup order.

Can you access VMs console? Are there any error messages?